# Django: exclude some objects

Tags: python, django

i want to exclude some user from the User model, who are exists in **friends**, **i_requested**, **requested_me** .

models.py:

```
class Relation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='my_friends', blank=True)
    i_requested = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='i_requested', blank=True)
    requested_me = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='requested_me', blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
def allUser(request):
    me = request.user
    f = Relation.objects.get(user=me)
    ff = f.friends.all()

    users = User.objects.all()
    exclude = users.exclude(id__in=ff)

    print(exclude)
    print(ff)

    serializer = SimpleUserSerializer(user, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

when i run this code, it prints:

**<QuerySet [<User: test5>, <User: test3>, <User: test2>]>**

**<QuerySet [<User: test5>]>**

why it don't exclude **test5**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here `f.friends.all()` returns list of objects.

in `exclude = users.exclude(id__in=ff)` you are comparing id with list of objects.

try in `exclude = users.exclude(id__in=ff.values_list('id', flat=True))`

upvote if it helps.